# PDF Template - HTML Form - Automatically Send To Email

Tags: html, forms, email, pdf

I was hoping I could get some insight as to how to perform the following on my website;

I have a PDF application that I would like users to be able to fill out and hit 'Submit' to automatically send the filled-out application to my email.

Would it be possible to have an editable pdf on a web page that they fill out on the web page? When they are done they would hit submit and it would send a copy of this filled-out pdf to my email

Would it be possible to have an **html** form that the user fills out and when they hit submit, it automatically creates a copy of the pdf, fills in the fields using the html form information, and sends it to my email?

I have very little knowledge when it comes to this so any sort of assistance would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to have an editable pdf on a web page that they fill out on the web page? When they are done they would hit submit and it would send a copy of this filled-out pdf to my email

I don't know about this.

> Would it be possible to have an html form that the user fills out and when they hit submit, it automatically creates a copy of the pdf, fills in the fields using the html form information, and sends it to my email?

I know about this.

You can do this by using **mpdf** and **PHPMailer** libraries. I am using them in my projects. I will soon paste here an example.